# Can't get the total amount of invites a user did

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the invites of the author of the command to the one server [Not multiple servers just one] I have tried many solutions but many seem outdated or wrong. Here is what I came up with

```
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    var user = message.author;
    message.guild.invites.fetch()
        .then(invites => {
             const userInvites = invites.filter(o => o.inviter.id === user.id);
             var userInviteCount = 0;
             console.log(userInvites['uses']);
             for (var i=0; i < userInvites.length; i++) {
                 var invite = userInvites[i];
                 userInviteCount += invite['uses'];
             }
             message.reply(`You have ${userInviteCount} invites.`);
         } )
}
```

This is in an invite.js file so when a user runs !invites it runs this command after exports.run

Comment: Can you please share what is going wrong when you run the code?

Comment: There is no error in the code it just does not want to tell me the exact number of invites instead it just tells me undefined in the console

Comment: You're using outdated code, please reference the latest Discord.js documentation!

Comment: I tried your code it gives the same result then the first one undefined

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working implementation from what you want to accomplish, a few notes:

1. A Slash command called invites was created to demo this functionality.
2. If you want to try the command on your own [you can join the demo server here](https://discord.gg/nTxU9Eqeyv)
3. [See attached screenshot of the working slash command](http://www.giphy.com/gifs/yvVBsdJUS71UjkloyS)
4. If you run the example, you will get all the created invites
5. If you want to filter by user id, you need to execute the slash command in Discord

| Responding to a slash command | [<kbd>Run in Fusebit [image]</kbd>](https://api.us-west-1.on.fusebit.io/v1/run/sub-c2eaf0578e7140ca/share/share/edit?integrationId=so-70681334) |
| --- | --- |

```js
// Respond to a Slash command
integration.event.on('/:componentName/webhook/:eventType', async (ctx) => {
  const {
    data: { application_id, token, member },
  } = ctx.req.body;

  // Store the user id that triggered the bot command.
  const commandTriggeredByUser = member.user.id;
  const discordClient = await integration.service.getSdk(ctx, connectorName, ctx.req.body.installIds[0]);
  const guildInvites = await discordClient.bot.get(`guilds/${DISCORD_DEMO_GUILD_ID}/invites`);

  // Filter the user created invites only
  const userCreatedInvites = guildInvites.filter(invite => invite.inviter.id === commandTriggeredByUser);

  // Reply to the slash command with the number of created invites
  await superagent.post(`https://discord.com/api/v8/webhooks/${application_id}/${token}`).send({
    content: `You have created ${userCreatedInvites.length} invites`,
  });
});
```